# JSON string has different format

Tags: json, string

I have 2 different `JSON` strings.

1st json string contains

```
\"StartDateString\":\"9/3/2016\"
```

and the second json string contains

```
\"StartDateString\":\"26\\/3\\/2016\"
```

Why the second one contains `\\` and first one include single `/`
what could be the initial data types assigned when create the JSON strings?

Answer (score 0):

```
\"StartDateString\":\"26\\/3\\/2016\"
```

In this json, **to escape `/ (forward slash)`character,another `/(forward slash)`** is used.You can remove it.

So,after removing it,

```
`\"StartDateString\":\"26/3/2016\"` is also valid one
```

Answer (score 0):

You are escaping the backward slash in the second json string pattern.

```
\"StartDateString\":\"26/3/2016\".
```

If you does not want you can remove it